# Updating the user

Tags: c#

I am having a grid in gridpage.aspx and on clicking the search button in gridpage.aspx. it opens a search popupwindow  with search criteria and  after entering the search criteria and clicking the search button in the popup window  will close the popup window and displays all the records in the gridpage.aspx.

the scenario is when i am retreiving lakhs of records i want to display the user with some update  that the search is still in progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear on how you are doing the whole popup logic (ie: client side code, update panel, etc). I'll go the simple route and assume you are using an UpdatePanel.

You could have a panel (div) on your page with a default visibility of false (css style = display: none) that contained an animated "loading" icon.

When the users clicks search you could change the visibility (css style = display: block) to true.

You could also accomplish this using javascript client side if clicking "Search" isn't already causing a postback.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of you can have div with an gif image and display that while the search is on. You can make it visible in the beginning of the method where search starts and hide it in the end.

If you are using UpdatePanel, go for UpdatePanelAnimator (or something like. Don't remember the exact name). It will also gove the same effect.